# How to set a default empty list in swagger codegen

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-codegen

There is an entity with a field

```
      cises:
        type: array
        description: An array of brands. The length must match the value of the quantity field, or the array must be empty
        items:
          type: string
```

Code java

```
  @SerializedName("cises")
  private List<String> cises = null;
```

How to use swagger codegen to set an empty list by default, instead of null

Comment: Try adding `default: []` on the same level as `type: array` - does this work?

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

There is an open issue with the *swagger codegen* ignoring the `default: []` for array.   See [[JAVA] Empty array not getting picked as default for the defined model in Open API AKA Swagger generated code](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/10874) for more information.
It's suggested to use `required` as a workaround for now.